# GWT:selection model not working properly

Tags: gwt

I have a celltable in GWT which have checkboxes, to select multiple checkboxes i am using selectionModel,once I check any checkbox its values get saved in the selectionModel,but then when i uncheck the checkbox , they never get remove , i want to remove the previous selection , how can it be possible

below is the code

```
        List<Categories> selected;


        display.getListWidget().getSelectionModel().addSelectionChangeHandler(new SelectionChangeEvent.Handler() {
        public void onSelectionChange(SelectionChangeEvent event) {

            selected = new ArrayList<Categories>(
                    ((MultiSelectionModel<Categories>) display.getListWidget().getSelectionModel()).getSelectedSet());

        }
    });
```

What i am trying to do is

```
        display.getListWidget().getSelectionModel().setSelected(categories, false);
```

but its not working , coz i guess categories is not the one which is already added ..

Any Suggestions

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could clarify your question with some more code or by being more specific, we might be able to give a better answer. From your question, I'm guessing that your Categories equals and hashcode are not overwritten in a way that the "categories" you are trying to set is being found.

I'm guessing a bit here but I think a KeyProvider will help you deselect the correct Categories object.

view:

```
SelectionModel<Categories> selectionModel;

ProvidesKey<Categories> keyProvider = new ProvidesKey<Categories>() {
    public Object getKey(Categories categories) {
      return item == null ? null : categories.id() // or some unique identifier
    }
};

CellTable cellTable = new CellTable<Categories>(keyProvider);

// Omitted..Add columns..

selectionModel = new MultiSelectionModel<Categories>(keyProvider);
cellTable.setSelectionModel(selectionModel);
```

presenter:

```
List<Categories> selected;

display.getListWidget().getSelectionMode().addSelectionChangeHandler(
    new SelectionChangeHandler() {
      public void onSelectionChange() {
        MultiSelectionModel selectionModel = 
            (MultiSelectionModel) display.getListWidget().getSelectionModel();
        selected = Lists.newArrayList(selectionModel.getSelectedSet());
      }
});
```